# How to build a (XAML) pull parser with Sprache?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, parsing, sprache

I’ve created a pull parser as part of my [OmniXaml](https://github.com/SuperJMN/OmniXaml) project. It reads an XML file and transforms it into an enumerable of XAML Nodes. But I'm not happy with the result, so I decided to try to build another in a more elegant way.

This is why I tried to make the parser using [Sprache](https://github.com/sprache/Sprache).

The thing is that I don’t even know how to start. XAML parsing heavily relies on context, so if you want to yield one Xaml Node, you might have to look-ahead and process the following nodes. I currently use an XmlReader to read the XAML.

Here I'm listing some EXAMPLES of inputs/outputs for you to figure out what I want to do. The input is a XAML code, and the output is a list of XAML nodes. XAML nodes are a structure in which I hold the data that is required to recreate the objects represented in the XAML. They are like instructions of a CPU.

**EXAMPLE 1**

Input (XAML):

```
<DummyClass xmlns="root" SampleProperty="Property!">  
</DummyClass>
```

Output (list of XAML Nodes)

- **Namespace Declaration** of "root" with prefix: ""
- **Start of Object** of type DummyClass
- **Start of Member** "SampleProperty" from type "DummyClass"
- **Value Node:** "Property!"
- **End Of Member**
- **None**
- **End of Object**

**EXAMPLE 2**

Input:

```
<DummyClass xmlns="root">
  <DummyClass.Child>
    <ChildClass></ChildClass>
  </DummyClass.Child>
</DummyClass>
```

Output:

- **Namespace Declaration** of "root" with prefix: ""
- **Start of Object** of type DummyClass
- **None**
- **Start of Member** "Child" from type "DummyClass"
- **Start of Object** of type "ChildClass"
- **None**
- **End of Object**
- **End of Member**
- **End of Object**

**EXAMPLE 3**

Input:

```
  <DummyClass xmlns="root">
    <DummyClass.Items>
      <Item/>
      <Item/>
      <Item/>
    </DummyClass.Items>
  </DummyClass>
```

Output:

- **Namespace Declaration** of "root" with prefix: ""
- **Start of Object** of type DummyClass
- **None**
- **Start of Member** “Items” from type “DummyClass”
- **[Get Object] Directive**
- **[Start of Items] Directive**
- **Start of Object** of type “Item”
- **None**
- **End of Object**
- **Start of Object** of type “Item”
- **None**
- **End of Object**
- **Start of Object** of type “Item”
- **None**
- **End of Object**
- **End of Member**
- **End of Object**
- **End of Member**
- **End of Object**

How can I start with this?

Are any samples/guidelines available?

Comment: It is not a real answer but you can look into [Kaxaml](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/kaxaml) for inspiration. Kaxaml is a free open source XAML editor.

Comment: Oh, thanks, but Kaxaml uses the XAML reading features that WPF provides, so it doesn't provide a pull parser: it uses the existing one, that is closed (in System.Xaml) :(

Comment: Ok sorry. Good luck.

Comment: You could maybe look at the Perspex project. On the `xaml` branch they're working on their own xaml parser: https://github.com/SuperJMN/Perspex/tree/xaml

Comment: Haha, but... hey! I'm the creator! I mean, I'm SuperJMN, the one that is creating the XAML parser :) In fact, I already have one, but I don't really like it. I would like to make a better one using Monadic Parser Combinators. I mentioned Sprache because it's the one I have already used, but any parser framework is welcome if it's as elegant. Thanks for the answer!